# Natural language automation?

Tags: automation, nlp

I remember reading about an automation program for windows that would accept a list of commands like this:

```
press the ok button
put "hello world" into the text control
press the add button
```

etc etc. Can anyone name this program? A thousand thankyous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at watin. http://watin.sourceforge.net/
Combined with Microsoft Oslo DSL. You can achieve this easily

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look for a port of AppleScript to Windows?  Assuming such a beast does not exist, perhaps something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) might be close enough?

Answer (score 0):

[ADL](http://adl.opengroup.org/) will generate natural language representations of your test cases (for documentation / stakeholder review).  I don't know of a tool that will go the other way.

There is also [Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/), which is about as close as I have seen to a natural language document which acts as a test.